# Iterating over multiple lists sequentially with list index in Python

Tags: python, iteration

I'm looking for a library function which iterates over multiple lists sequentially, producing their elements and the index of the list the element is taken from. For example, this code:

```py
a = [9, 1]
b = [3, 42]

for i, e in magic_chain(a, b):
  print(i, e)
```

would produce:

```py
0 9
0 1
1 3
1 42
```

Does anything like this exist? I know how to write it, but I'm looking for existing library functionality.

Comment: No, but we might be able to show you something closer to it than yours if you show it.

Answer (score 2):

use [enumerate](https://realpython.com/python-enumerate/#using-pythons-enumerate):

```py
a = [9, 1]
b = [3, 42]
for i, lst in enumerate([a, b]):
    for e in lst:
        print(i, e)
```

Comment: Good idea. I simplified it a bit.

Comment: @PaulJurczak Now I'm really curious what your own idea was. I thought this (the simplified version) is what you had in mind.

Comment: @KellyBundy I wish. I was going to write two separate loops, one for `a`, one for `b`. Somehow this simple option didn't occur to me. Python beginner.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of anything that does exactly what you're looking for (at least, out of the functions in `itertools`). But, using `chain()` and `repeat()`, we can get something fairly concise that can be extended to an arbitrary number of iterables:

```py
from itertools import chain, repeat

a = [9, 1]
b = [3, 42]

for i, e in chain.from_iterable(zip(repeat(idx), itr) for idx, itr in enumerate([a, b])):
  print(i, e)
```

Answer (score 1):

Not a single function, but we can combine a few to get a fast solution:

```
def magic_chain(*lists):
    return chain.from_iterable(map(zip, map(repeat, count()), lists))
```

A benchmark:

```
60.7 ms  magic_chain1
12.4 ms  magic_chain2
```

Code ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZVHJasMwEL37K@YSIgdj7KaHEsiXhCIUe5IItEUeH9Kfd2fsZqMC4eVto6d0o0sM26@Up8nZgQbYw@HQfMMG2qZ5PIuixxN4c7ad7i7GhlZtZnq5K4DXKWawFbiBwAbAMHrMhlC9cu48FAozn39l3Sy6XjzwX9bHe1ZGGnOAGapPOXptidOODpU3Sf3YVIG8ZExoqIIujoFUWfJ4s0tZFKICsh4tz@tTzPT3tSBddA47sjEMd7jH64gLKmkUo3tg8yQVvOVxxhg6afO1tOrtWMzhOrTUkU04o9q@tClyQWabZ1XEjsuoyhl/7M1uGU0J795TBQ1vvoQj5n1bPsQpW25ivfqsWy54gDWsQJFcMW5ZIBa11sF41HpRLYpymn4B)):

```
lists = [[0] * 1000] * 1000

def magic_chain1(*lists):
    for i, lst in enumerate(lists):
        for e in lst:
            yield i, e

def magic_chain2(*lists):
    return chain.from_iterable(map(zip, map(repeat, count()), lists))

from timeit import timeit
from collections import deque
from itertools import chain, repeat, count

funcs = magic_chain1, magic_chain2

for _ in range(3):
    for func in funcs:
        t = timeit(lambda: deque(func(*lists), 0), number=1)
        print('%4.1f ms ' % (t * 1e3), func.__name__)
    print()
```

Comment: Thank you for benchmarking it. I'm surprised `magic_chain2` is so much faster.